# Problem in creating new Flutter project with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins, flutter, project

I want to create a sample Flutter project with Android Studio but the problem is although I installed Flutter and Flutter language plugin in Android Studio 3.2.1 the menu is missing in File > New.
I also downloaded the Flutter SDK and configured environment variables. Following is my flutter doctor result:

```
- Flutter (Channel stable, v1.0.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601], locale en-US)
 . Flutter version 1.0.0 at C:\flutter
 . Framework revision 5391447fae (7 weeks ago), 2018-11-29 19:41:26 -0800
 . Engine revision 7375a0f414
 . Dart version 2.1.0 (build 2.1.0-dev.9.4 f9ebf21297)

- Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
 . Android SDK at C:\sdk
 . Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
 . Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
 . ANDROID_HOME = C:\sdk
 . Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
 . Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
 . All Android licenses accepted.

- Android Studio (version 2.3)
  . Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio v2
  . Flutter plugin version 12.1 - the recommended minimum version is 16.0.0
  . Dart plugin version 162.2924
  . Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-release-b06)

- Android Studio (version 3.2)
  . Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
  . Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
  . Dart plugin version 181.5656
  . Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

+ IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 15)
 . IntelliJ at C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 15.0.6
 . Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
 . Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
 . For information about installing plugins, see
 .  https://flutter.io/intellij-setup/#installing-the-plugins
 . This install is older than the minimum recommended version of 2017.1.0.

-IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2018.3)
   .  IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3.2
   .  Flutter plugin version 31.3.4
   .  Dart plugin version 183.4886.3

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: What is your Windows version? It looks like you're not using Windows 7+?

Comment: seriously?  did you restart Android studio?

Comment: Pete Houston, I'm using windows 7 ultimate service pack 1, is it important which version I'm using?

Comment: Kenneth Li, Yes and also my windows :-)

Comment: Please post the output of `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer, It seems to be my 'flutter doctor -v' result, did you edit that?

Comment: @user2240957 yes, he helped you to edit the post; otherwise, your post will be closed.

Comment: @Pete Houston, Why would my question be closed? Thanks to him anyhow, but I don't think closing my question was right.

Comment: @user2240957 you want others to help, you need to make sure your question content is readable, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 9):

Try enabling the plugins `Android APK Support` & `Android NDK Support`.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem (Android Studio 3.5 on a Mac with Catalina).

In Android Studio > Go to Preferences > Plugins and you will see both plugins (dart & flutter) disabled.

Click 'update', 'enable' and then the suggested 'restart IDE'.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My `flutter doctor` result is almost the same as yours, just only one difference.

I don't install two version of Android Studio, and I don't install this one `- Android Studio (version 2.3)`.

Comment: I'm an android developer @Pete Houston, so I have to install multiple IDEs on my machine. I don't think this is the cause of my problem!

Comment: yup, I develop Android apps too, and I only need one single Android Studio version to build apps.

Comment: @user2240957 Open Android Studio v3, access Plugins dialog, check version of Flutter plugin, is it 31.3.1 or 12.1?

Comment: my Flutter plugin version is 31.3.1

Comment: @user2240957 how about removing both Flutter/Dart plugins on your Android Studio v3. Restart AS, then install them again.

Answer (score 0):

Updating Android Studio solved the problem for me.